# Clickable listbox to open text document VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, listbox

this is my code

```
Dim InputStr As String = CrystalClearTextBox1.Text

    For Each FileStr As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\Users\root\Desktop\databases", "*.txt")

        If IO.File.ReadAllText(FileStr).IndexOf(InputStr) >= 0 Then

            ListBox1.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(FileStr))
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add("No Results found!")

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Also instead of just .txt, is it possible to add .csv, .sql?

What I am trying to do is when it returns the text file it is located into to be able to click it and open the textfile and scroll to where the word is inside that text file, is this possible? If you would help me I would greatly appcreiate it!

Comment: nevermind about sql and csv just need to know how to click the listbox file now.

Comment: Do you want the file name without extension in the listbox, but be able to open different file types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 questions. I'll give the first one, then make a different topic for that one.

```
Dim files = New DirectoryInfo("your directory").GetFiles()

'set the data source
lsb.DataSource = files

'this will be the display in the listbox
lsb.DisplayMember = "Name"

'this is the full path for opening the file
lsb.ValueMember = "FullName"
```

Usage - in the listbox selectedIndexChanged event.

```
'this will open whatever program is need to open the document
Process.Start(lsv.SelectedValue.ToString)
```

Comment: Ok I did it a different way but now what I want to do is when it opens the text file I want it to automatically do what the find feature does in notepad, is that possible?

Comment: That is question #2 open a new topic. If my answer help mark as appropriate.

Comment: it won't let me, I reached my limit.

Comment: It's been 0 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you wait 6 days before asking again.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to use the find function when opening a process.